# Add column with number of days between dates in DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date-difference

I want to subtract dates in 'A' from dates in 'B' and add a new column with the difference.

```
df
          A        B
one 2014-01-01  2014-02-28 
two 2014-02-03  2014-03-01
```

I've tried the following, but get an error when I try to include this in a for loop...

```
import datetime
date1=df['A'][0]
date2=df['B'][0]
mdate1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
rdate1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
delta =  (mdate1 - rdate1).days
print delta
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Assuming these were datetime columns (if they're not apply `to_datetime`) you can just subtract them:

```
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])

In [11]: df.dtypes  # if already datetime64 you don't need to use to_datetime
Out[11]:
A    datetime64[ns]
B    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [12]: df['A'] - df['B']
Out[12]:
one   -58 days
two   -26 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [13]: df['C'] = df['A'] - df['B']

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
             A          B        C
one 2014-01-01 2014-02-28 -58 days
two 2014-02-03 2014-03-01 -26 days
```

*Note: ensure you're using a new of pandas (e.g. 0.13.1), this may not work in older versions.*

Comment: Do can we get rid of the "days" portion in the result incase we just need to see the numeric value ie. -58, -26 in this case.

Comment: to expand on @AndyHayden comment, that works but it should `pd.offsets.Day(1)` (with an 's').  I also usually negate it, so you get `(df['A'] - df['B']) / pd.offsets.Day(-1)`

Comment: However, if you want to do this on a whole Series you need `(df['A'] - df['B']) / np.timedelta64(-1, 'D')` for reasons that I don't fully understand.

Comment: @dirkjot Thanks for spotting the typo! IIRC this was fix in recent pandas, are you using 0.16.2 / 0.17?

Comment: I found that this was a bit buggy when there was missing data. The problems are that 1) the missing data doesn't have an `.isnull()` attribute and 2) it has a `.day` attribute but the non-missing data has a `.days` attribute. So after creating the new variable I ran a loop over each `obs`ervation that checks: `if hasattr(obs,'days')` then assign `obs.days` and else assign `np.nan`.

Comment: @webelo the DatetimeIndex/Series itself should have a `.dt.days` attribute which should be strongly preferred.

Comment: In case we have a constant date on one hand and a series on another hand we can do `d0 = pd.to_datetime(date(2017, 2, 28))`
`d1 = df.Date`
`delta = d1 - d0`

Answer (score 201):

To remove the 'days' text element, you can also make use of the dt() accessor for series: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html

So,

```
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].apply(pd.to_datetime) #if conversion required
df['C'] = (df['B'] - df['A']).dt.days
```

which returns:

```
             A          B   C
one 2014-01-01 2014-02-28  58
two 2014-02-03 2014-03-01  26
```

Comment: Great answer.  In my case, `df['C'] = (df['B'] - df['A']).dt.days` did not work and I had to use `df['C'] = (df['B'] - df['A']).days`. Any idea why mine did not give the number of days as expected?

Comment: Nde - how exactly did it not work?  Error or wrong values?  Did you convert both A and B columns to datetime successfully?

Comment: Both my columns are datetime (or `datetime64[ns]` to be precise). When I did `df['C'] = (df['B'] - df['A']).dt.days`, I got an attribute error that said **AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'dt'**, so I tried **df['C'] = (df['B'] - df['A']).days** which gave me the desired answer. (Of course I am using my own dataframe not the one in the example above. Or could it be because I also have time in my date and not as in `2018-09-24 10:17:18.800277`)

Comment: How does this function rounds, if my original dataframe is with Hours:Minutes:Seconds?

Comment: one small suggestion, use df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A']) is much faster than using apply function,

Answer (score 14):

A list comprehension is your best bet for the most Pythonic (and fastest) way to do this:

```
[int(i.days) for i in (df.B - df.A)]
```

1. i will return the timedelta(e.g. '-58 days')
2. i.days will return this value as a long integer value(e.g. -58L)
3. int(i.days) will give you the -58 you seek.

If your columns aren't in datetime format. The shorter syntax would be: `df.A = pd.to_datetime(df.A)`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
times['days_since'] = max(list(df.index.values))  
times['days_since'] = times['days_since'] - times['months']  
times
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution above did not work for me. If you are using a simple `pd.to_datetime()` to first convert it, later you can just use:

```
import numpy as np

df['C'] = df['A'] - df['B'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```