# Pandas - cross columns reference

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

My `data` is a bit complicated, I separate into 2 sections: (A) Explain data, (B) Desire output

**(A) - Explain data:**

My `data` as follow:

```
   comp       date   adj_date  val
0     a 1999-12-31        NaT   50
1     a 2000-01-31        NaT   51
2     a 2000-02-29        NaT   52
3     a 2000-03-31        NaT   53
4     a 2000-04-30        NaT   54
5     a 2000-05-31        NaT   55
6     a 2000-06-30        NaT   56
----------------------------------
7     a 2000-07-31 2000-01-31   57
8     a 2000-08-31 2000-02-29   58
9     a 2000-09-30 2000-03-31   59
10    a 2000-10-31 2000-04-30   60
11    a 2000-11-30 2000-05-31   61
12    a 2000-12-31 2000-06-30   62
13    a 2001-01-31 2000-07-31   63
14    a 2001-02-28 2000-08-31   64
15    a 2001-03-31 2000-09-30   65
16    a 2001-04-30 2000-10-31   66
17    a 2001-05-31 2000-11-30   67
18    a 2001-06-30 2000-12-31   68
----------------------------------
19    a 2001-07-31 2001-01-31   69
20    a 2001-08-31 2001-02-28   70
21    a 2001-09-30 2001-03-31   71
22    a 2001-10-31 2001-04-30   72
23    a 2001-11-30 2001-05-31   73
24    a 2001-12-31 2001-06-30   74
25    a 2002-01-31 2001-07-31   75
26    a 2002-02-28 2001-08-31   76
27    a 2002-03-31 2001-09-30   77
28    a 2002-04-30 2001-10-31   78
29    a 2002-05-31 2001-11-30   79
30    a 2002-06-30 2001-12-31   80
----------------------------------
31    a 2002-07-31 2002-01-31   81
32    a 2002-08-31 2002-02-28   82
33    a 2002-09-30 2002-03-31   83
34    a 2002-10-31 2002-04-30   84
35    a 2002-11-30 2002-05-31   85
36    a 2002-12-31 2002-06-30   86
37    a 2003-01-31 2002-07-31   87
38    a 2003-02-28 2002-08-31   88
39    a 2003-03-31 2002-09-30   89
40    a 2003-04-30 2002-10-31   90
41    a 2003-05-31 2002-11-30   91
42    a 2003-06-30 2002-12-31   92
----------------------------------
```

- `date`: is the actual date, as end of month.
- `adj_date` = `date` + `MonthEnd(-6)`
- `val`: is given value

I want to create new column `val_new` where:

- it is referencing to `val` of previous year December
- `val_new` is then applied to `date` as from `date.July` to `date.(year+1).June`, Or equivalently in `adj_date` it is from `adj_date.Jan` to `adj_date.Dec`

**(B) - Desire Output:**

```
   comp       date   adj_date  val  val_new
0     a 1999-12-31        NaT   50      NaN
1     a 2000-01-31        NaT   51      NaN
2     a 2000-02-29        NaT   52      NaN
3     a 2000-03-31        NaT   53      NaN
4     a 2000-04-30        NaT   54      NaN
5     a 2000-05-31        NaT   55      NaN
6     a 2000-06-30        NaT   56      NaN
-------------------------------------------
7     a 2000-07-31 2000-01-31   57     50.0
8     a 2000-08-31 2000-02-29   58     50.0
9     a 2000-09-30 2000-03-31   59     50.0
10    a 2000-10-31 2000-04-30   60     50.0
11    a 2000-11-30 2000-05-31   61     50.0
12    a 2000-12-31 2000-06-30   62     50.0
13    a 2001-01-31 2000-07-31   63     50.0
14    a 2001-02-28 2000-08-31   64     50.0
15    a 2001-03-31 2000-09-30   65     50.0
16    a 2001-04-30 2000-10-31   66     50.0
17    a 2001-05-31 2000-11-30   67     50.0
18    a 2001-06-30 2000-12-31   68     50.0
-------------------------------------------
19    a 2001-07-31 2001-01-31   69     62.0
20    a 2001-08-31 2001-02-28   70     62.0
21    a 2001-09-30 2001-03-31   71     62.0
22    a 2001-10-31 2001-04-30   72     62.0
23    a 2001-11-30 2001-05-31   73     62.0
24    a 2001-12-31 2001-06-30   74     62.0
25    a 2002-01-31 2001-07-31   75     62.0
26    a 2002-02-28 2001-08-31   76     62.0
27    a 2002-03-31 2001-09-30   77     62.0
28    a 2002-04-30 2001-10-31   78     62.0
29    a 2002-05-31 2001-11-30   79     62.0
30    a 2002-06-30 2001-12-31   80     62.0
-------------------------------------------
31    a 2002-07-31 2002-01-31   81     74.0
32    a 2002-08-31 2002-02-28   82     74.0
33    a 2002-09-30 2002-03-31   83     74.0
34    a 2002-10-31 2002-04-30   84     74.0
35    a 2002-11-30 2002-05-31   85     74.0
36    a 2002-12-31 2002-06-30   86     74.0
37    a 2003-01-31 2002-07-31   87     74.0
38    a 2003-02-28 2002-08-31   88     74.0
39    a 2003-03-31 2002-09-30   89     74.0
40    a 2003-04-30 2002-10-31   90     74.0
41    a 2003-05-31 2002-11-30   91     74.0
42    a 2003-06-30 2002-12-31   92     74.0
-------------------------------------------
```

I have two solutions, but both comes at a cost:

- Solution 1: to create `sub_dec` dataframe where we take `val` of `Dec` each year. Then merge back to main `data`. This one works fine, but I don't like this solution because our actual data will involve a lot of merge, and it is not easy and convenient to keep track of all those merges.
- Solution 2: (1) I create a lag by shift(7), (2) set other `adj_date` but Jan to `None`, (3) then use groupby with ffill. This solution works nicely, but if there is any missing rows, or the date is not continuous, then the entire `output` is wrong

###### create `adj_year`:

```
data['adj_year'] = data['adj_date'].dt.year
```

###### cross referencing by `shift(7)`:

```
data['val_new'] = data.groupby('comp')['val'].shift(7)
```

###### setting other `adj_date` except Jan to be `None`:

```
data.loc[data['adj_date'].dt.month != 1, 'val_new'] = None
```

###### using ffill to fill in None by each group of `['comp', 'adj_year']`:

```
data['val_new'] = data.groupby(['comp', 'adj_year'])['val_new'].ffill()
```

If you have any suggestion to overcome the drawback of Solution 02, or any other new solution is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timedelta` with correct conversion from seconds to months, according to your needs ,

check these two resources for more info:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html
- [pandas: function equivalent to SQL's datediff()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078370/pandas-function-equivalent-to-sqls-datediff)