Subtract columns with data of type date in python
I have the next example
import pandas as pd
    
data = {
    'id_number': ['000001000', '000009795', '000011722'],
    'first_date': ['2022-01-08 13:41:00', '2022-11-07 09:16:00', '2022-02-15 12:46:00'],
    'last_date': ['2023-06-13 16:33:00', '2022-11-30 12:59:00', '2022-06-21 11:42:00']
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Try to calculate the difference in months
df_test['first_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['first_date'])
df_test['last_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['last_date'])
df_test['months_difference'] = (df_test['last_date'] - df_test['first_date']) // pd.Timedelta('1 month')

df_test

But the error is
ValueError: invalid unit abbreviation: month

Is there any way to calculate that difference?

Use a time delta that actually exists? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html (30 days, or 30.5 days, or whatever you decide is "a month")

1 month cannot be a timedelta because it is an inaccurate interval ranging from 28 to 31 days.

Or, perhaps you want this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73645235/53341

another option: convert datetime to period "M" (months), then to integer (gives you the number of months since 1970), then do the subtraction:
df_test["last_date"].dt.to_period("M").astype(int)-df_test["first_date"].dt.to_period("M").astype(int)

0    17
1     0
2     4
dtype: int64


df_test["last_date"].dt.to_period("M").astype('int64')-df_test["first_date"].dt.to_period("M").astype('int64')
got an error and had to change the form

@danny right, using just int is for pandas v2+. might not work with older versions.

You can try the following:
df_test['months_difference'] = (df_test.last_date -df_test.first_date)/numpy.timedelta64(1, 'M')

This will give you the months difference as a float, if you want them as integers, add
df_test['months_difference'] = df_test['months_difference'].astype(int)


I thinkg pandas and numpy no longer accept that abbreviation of 'M' becaouse I got this error
ValueError: Unit M is not supported. Only unambiguous timedelta values durations are supported. Allowed units are 'W', 'D', 'h', 'm', 's', 'ms', 'us', 'ns'

I found this solution:
    # Create the DataFrame
data = {
    'id_number': ['000001000', '000009795', '000011722'],
    'first_date': ['2022-01-08 13:41:00', '2022-11-07 09:16:00', '2022-02-15 12:46:00'],
    'last_date': ['2023-06-13 16:33:00', '2022-11-30 12:59:00', '2022-06-21 11:42:00']
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert date columns to datetime
df_test['first_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['first_date'])
df_test['last_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['last_date'])

# Calculate difference in months based on days
df_test['months_difference'] = ((df_test['last_date'] - df_test['first_date']).dt.days) // 30.44 
#30.44 is avg of days per month in a non-leap yer

or using this:
df_test['months_difference'] = df_test['last_date'].dt.to_period('M').astype('int64') - df_test['first_date'].dt.to_period('M').astype('int64')

