# get date difference from dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to add a column to a dataframe based on another existing columns

the dataframe is in the following format

```
col1         col2 
2017-02-1    2017-03-03
2017-02-22   2017-03-06


from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
df['TimeConsumed']=df['col2'].apply(lambda x: (datetime.strptime(x,date_format)-datetime.strptime(df['col1'],date_format)).days)
```

run the above and it keeps getting

```
TypeError: must be string, not Series
```

anyone please a little help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add column with number of days between dates in DataFrame pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132525/add-column-with-number-of-days-between-dates-in-dataframe-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error happens because you try to **do strptime on Series, which only support string**:

```
datetime.strptime(df['col1'], date_format)
```

I think you want to subtract on each row, then you need to apply on row, other than on one column, like below:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


def substract(df):
    date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    return (datetime.strptime(df['col2'],date_format)-    datetime.strptime(df['col1'],date_format)).days

if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = pd.DataFrame([{'col1':'2017-02-01','col2':'2017-03-03'},{'col1':'2017-02-22','col2':'2017-03-06'}])
    print df

    #date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    #df['TimeConsumed']=df['col2'].apply(lambda x: (datetime.strptime(x,date_format)-datetime.strptime(df['col1'],date_format)).days)
    df["TimeConsumed"] = df.apply(substract, axis=1)
    print df
```

Output:

```
        col1        col2  TimeConsumed
0  2017-02-01  2017-03-03            30
1  2017-02-22  2017-03-06            12
```

Comment: just tested, it works. but im wondering why "datetime.strptime(x,date_format)" in my code is applying to series, i thought in the lambda  function, it applies to each cell of that column. am i wrong about this ?

Comment: and in your code there are also "datetime.strptime(df['col2'],date_format)" same as mine, im confused, how is the same code works for you but not me

Comment: when called df.apply(func), actually that func will work on each row, which means df['col1'] and df['col2'] inside func are string other than series. For your code, it's df['col2'].apply, so that works on each row in df['col2'] (Series), while df['col1'] inside it is still Series other than string.

Comment: so that mean "datetime.strptime(df['col1'],date_format)" should work outside of that lambda function, right?

Comment: no, datetime.strpttime only accepts string as input. The reason why it works in my code is because we use apply on that function, from doc http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html, you could see apply is used to call func on each row, which means actuall df['col1'] inside the func is string other than Series :)

Comment: isnt the part inside lambda a function too?  how do I apply a function with lambda then in this case? thanks a lot

Comment: no, it's not related with lambda directly, but with who do apply. For your origin code, you do apply on df['col2'], which means func will be called on each row on df['col2'], which not related with col1. For my answer, I do apply on df, which means func call on each row on both col1 and col2