# Applymap interface for operations on several(two) columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose i have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_1':['2010-11-06', '2010-10-07', '2010-09-07', '2010-05-07'],
                       'DATE_2':['2010-12-07', '2010-11-06', '2010-10-07', '2010-08-06']})
df['DATE_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_1'])
df['DATE_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_2'])
```

So it look like:

```
      DATE_1      DATE_2
0   2010-11-06  2010-12-07
1   2010-10-07  2010-11-06
2   2010-09-07  2010-10-07
3   2010-05-07  2010-08-06
```

I want to create another column `DIFF` which is diffrence of `DATE_2` and `DATE_1` in days or months or years.
**I want to have** an interface like the one, which is under these words, **because** i'll have to create **a lot of** columns, similar to `DIFF` from **a lot of** `DATE_X` columns:

```
def date_diffrence(x, y, parameter):
    if !np.isnan(x):
         return (x-y)
df['DIFF'] = df.apply(date_diffrence(df['DATE_2'], df['DATE_1']))
```

According to this post: [Difference between map, applymap and apply methods in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas), it seems to me, that i'm not able to create such a universal interface. Am i right?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132525/add-column-with-number-of-days-between-dates-in-dataframe-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need function without `apply` with `Series` (columns of `df`) as arguments with [`dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
def date_diffrence_days(x, y):
    return (x-y).dt.days

df['DIFF'] = date_diffrence_days(df['DATE_2'], df['DATE_1'])
print (df)
      DATE_1     DATE_2  DIFF
0 2010-11-06 2010-12-07    31
1 2010-10-07 2010-11-06    30
2 2010-09-07 2010-10-07    30
3 2010-05-07 2010-08-06    91
```

What is same as:

```
df['DIFF'] = (df['DATE_2'] - df['DATE_1']).dt.days
print (df)
      DATE_1     DATE_2  DIFF
0 2010-11-06 2010-12-07    31
1 2010-10-07 2010-11-06    30
2 2010-09-07 2010-10-07    30
3 2010-05-07 2010-08-06    91
```

EDIT:

```
def date_diffrence_days(x, y, parameter):
    if parameter == 'm':
        return (x-y).dt.days
    elif parameter == 's':
        return (x-y).dt.total_seconds()

df['DIFF'] = date_diffrence_days(df['DATE_2'], df['DATE_1'], 's')
print (df)
      DATE_1     DATE_2       DIFF
0 2010-11-06 2010-12-07  2678400.0
1 2010-10-07 2010-11-06  2592000.0
2 2010-09-07 2010-10-07  2592000.0
3 2010-05-07 2010-08-06  7862400.0
```

Comment: Hm, that's true. My fault - not very familiar with DataFrames

Comment: Could you please update your answer if i update my question with an addition option?

Comment: Do you think `!np.isnan(x):` ?

Comment: Actually, no;) Now i see, that i'd like to have an option in `date_diffrence_days` - to choose: whether to return days or months or years. So it is: `date_diffrence_days(x,y,parameter)`. And seems like delta doesnt have `.monts` or '.year' option

Comment: You can check edit. If need `years` or months, I think the best is use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/765812/2901002)