# How to find number of days between today and future date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a field named 'MATURITY' in a dataframe.  One sample date looks like this:

```
2026-05-21
```

I'm trying to add a new field to the dataframe and find the difference between each maturity date and today.  How can I do that?  I tried the following:

```
df['DaysToMaturity'] = pd.to_datetime((df['MATURITY'] - date.today()).days)
```

That gives me this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'datetime.date'
```

That should be pretty close, I believe, but obviously something is off here.  Thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add column with number of days between dates in DataFrame pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132525/add-column-with-number-of-days-between-dates-in-dataframe-pandas)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `pandas.Timestamp`

```
df['DaysToMaturity'] = (df['MATURITY'] - pd.Timestamp('now')).dt.days
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but the formatting is wacky.  I'm seeing this: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002504
The 2504 is the number of days, but how can I just get that?

Comment: df['DaysToMaturity'] = pd.to_numeric(df['DaysToMaturity'])

Answer (score 2):

**try this:**

```
from datetime import date
f_date = date.today()
l_date = date(2026, 5, 21)
delta = l_date - f_date
print(delta.days)
```

Comment: @Alessio Thank you for your advice.   I will try to explain more about the answers. ⁦❤️⁩⁦‍⁩