# how to calculate elapsed time in days and hours

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hi everyone I have two columns in datetime format and I want to make a new column with the elapsed time in days and a second column containing the rest in hours. please see the exemple:

my data :

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# creating a dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_IDENTIFIED': ['2019-06-27 10:42:50 ', '2019-06-28 13:11:58', '2019-06-20 13:12:23','2019-06-26 11:14:59','2019-06-26 11:16:04'], 
   'DATE_CLOSED': ['2019-09-27 10:40:38', '2019-06-28 19:11:22', 
   '2019-06-28 18:11:22','2019-06-26 13:13:38','2019-06-28 14:15:37']}) 


DATE_IDENTIFIED                   DATE_CLOSED
0   2019-06-27 10:42:50           2019-06-27 10:40:38
1   2019-06-28 13:11:58           2019-06-28 13:11:22
2   2019-06-28 13:12:23           2019-06-28 13:11:22
3   2019-06-26 11:14:59           2019-06-26 11:13:38
4   2019-06-26 11:16:04           2019-06-26 11:15:37
```

Example

```
DATE_IDENTIFIED                   DATE_CLOSED         days       hours
2019-06-27 10:42:50           2019-09-27 10:40:38        90        0
2019-06-28 13:11:58           2019-06-28 19:11:22         0        6
2019-06-20 13:12:23           2019-06-28 18:11:22         8        5
2019-06-26 11:14:59           2019-06-26 13:13:38         0        2
2019-06-26 11:16:04           2019-06-28 14:15:37         2        3
```

Comment: Can you post code to generate that dataframe

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
### first convert your columns to datetime object if it is not already
df['DATE_IDENTIFIED']  = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_IDENTIFIED'])
df['DATE_CLOSED']  = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_CLOSED'])

### GET DAYS LIKE THIS
df['days'] = (df['DATE_CLOSED'] - df['DATE_IDENTIFIED']).dt.days

### GET HOURS LIKE THIS
df['hours'] = df['DATE_CLOSED'].dt.hour - df['DATE_IDENTIFIED'].dt.hour
```

Output:

```
      DATE_IDENTIFIED         DATE_CLOSED  days  hours
0 2019-06-27 10:42:50 2019-09-27 10:40:38    91      0
1 2019-06-28 13:11:58 2019-06-28 19:11:22     0      6
2 2019-06-20 13:12:23 2019-06-28 18:11:22     8      5
3 2019-06-26 11:14:59 2019-06-26 13:13:38     0      2
4 2019-06-26 11:16:04 2019-06-28 14:15:37     2      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something along the line of the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45039811/2186184) might get you started:

```
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])

df['C'] = (df['B'] - df['A']).dt.days
```

For the remaining hours you might need to do some additional math by for instance converting the difference in hours and subtracting the number of days times 24 hours

```
df['B'] = (df['B'] - df['A']).dt.hours - df['C'] * 24
```