# How to subtract date and time in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data from Pandas which was the contents of a CSV file:

```
Date                Inbound     Outbound
17/10/2019 12:35    5.49E+02    3.95E+03 
17/10/2019 12:40    2.06E+02    3.17E+03 
17/10/2019 12:45    2.06E+02    3.17E+03 
17/10/2019 12:50    2.06E+02    3.17E+03 
17/10/2019 12:55    2.06E+02    3.17E+03 
17/10/2019 13:00    2.06E+02    3.17E+03
....
```

I aim to convert the column `Date` from timestamps to time periods in units of minutes, which should result in something like the following:

```
    Date        Inbound     Outbound
    0           5.49E+02    3.95E+03 
    5           2.06E+02    3.17E+03 
    10          2.06E+02    3.17E+03 
    15          2.06E+02    3.17E+03 
    20          2.06E+02    3.17E+03 
    25          2.06E+02    3.17E+03
```

Comment: You can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132525/add-column-with-number-of-days-between-dates-in-dataframe-pandas

Comment: What problem do you run into? What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subtract the first timestampe to calculate the difference, then get `total_seconds()` and convert to minutes:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Date'] = (df.Date.sub(df.Date.iloc[0])
   .dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(int)
)
```

Output:

```
   Date  Inbound  Outbound
0     0    549.0    3950.0
1     5    206.0    3170.0
2    10    206.0    3170.0
3    15    206.0    3170.0
4    20    206.0    3170.0
5    25    206.0    3170.0
```

Comment: Something wrong with the implementation, it cannot be ran!

Comment: @TimLuka - I think is necessary `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` first

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
"17/10/2019 12:35",  
"17/10/2019 12:40",  
"17/10/2019 12:45", 
"17/10/2019 12:50",  
"17/10/2019 12:55",  
"17/10/2019 13:00",
    ]

columns = ["Date"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
# Because the values came in frm a CSV, they are not datetime objects. 
# Convert the column to datetime ojects
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
subtractdate = df["Date"].iloc[0]
df["Diff"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x - subtractdate)    
print(df)
```

**EDIT:**

To get the minutes, do the following...

```
df["Diff"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: (x - subtractdate).seconds/60)
```

(x - subtractdate) returns a `timedelta` object. It doesn't have a "minutes" option, but does have a seconds. This will return in a `float` format (I.e. `5.0`, `10.0`)

To get it as a string, do the following:

```
df["Diff"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: str( (x - subtractdate).seconds/60  ) )
```

And to get it as an int:

```
df["Diff"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: int( (x - subtractdate).seconds/60  ) )
```

The `int` will be the "5, 10, 15" format.

Comment: Thanks! actually it does show like  `00:00:00  00:05:00  00:10:00 ... ` I only want to show the difference without the timing thing. `0, 5, 10, 15 ...`