# Efficient way to calculate difference from pandas datetime columns based on days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a few million rows where I want to calculate the difference on a daily basis between two columns which are in datetime format.

There are stack overflow questions which answer this question computing the difference on a timestamp basis ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132525/add-column-with-number-of-days-between-dates-in-dataframe-pandas)

Doing it on the timestamp basis felt quite fast:
`df["Differnce"] = (df["end_date"] - df["start_date"]).dt.days`

But doing it on a daily basis felt quite slow:
`df["Differnce"] = (df["end_date"].dt.date - df["start_date"].dt.date).dt.days`

I was wondering if there is a easy but better/faster way to achieve the same result?

Example Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Condition' :["a", "a", "b"],
        'start_date': [pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01 23:00:00.000000'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01 23:00:00.000000'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01 23:00:00.000000')],
        'end_date': [pd.Timestamp('2022-01-02 01:00:00.000000'), pd.Timestamp('2022-02-01 23:00:00.000000'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-02 01:00:00.000000')]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Right_Difference"] = np.where((df["Condition"] == "a"), ((df["end_date"].dt.date - df["start_date"].dt.date).dt.days), np.nan)
df["Wrong_Difference"] = np.where((df["Condition"] == "a"), ((df["end_date"] - df["start_date"]).dt.days), np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), faster is [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) or [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html)    :

```
#300k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

In [286]: %timeit (df["end_date"].dt.date - df["start_date"].dt.date).dt.days
1.14 s ± 135 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [287]: %timeit df["end_date"].dt.to_period('d').astype('int') - df["start_date"].dt.to_period('d').astype('int')
64.1 ms ± 3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [288]: %timeit (df["end_date"].dt.normalize() - df["start_date"].dt.normalize()).dt.days
27.7 ms ± 316 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [289]: %timeit (df["end_date"].dt.floor('d') - df["start_date"].dt.floor('d')).dt.days
27.7 ms ± 937 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```